# Are there any functions $f$ beyond trivial examples where $\int f(x +f(x + f(x +\dotsb)))\,dx$ $= F(x+F(x+F(x +\dotsb))) + C$ for some function $F$?

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, functional-equations

Basically the title explains most of my question here. Purely out of curiosity (I have no real application), I am wondering if there are any "interesting" functions $f$ where we know of a function $F$ (perhaps $f$'s antiderivative, but not necessarily) such that

$$\int f(x + f(x + f(x + \dotsb)))\,dx = F(x + F(x + F(x + \dotsb))) + C.$$

One obvious case where this is true: $f(x) = 0$, $F(x) = 0$.

Are there any other examples where $f$ is doing any real transformation? Or is such a pair $f$ and $F$ impossible?

Comment: What do you mean by that infinite composition of functions?

Comment: @No-one, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460341/are-there-any-functions-f-beyond-trivial-examples-where-int-fx-fx-fx#comment1193851_460341), presumably a solution $\phi$ of the functional equation $\phi(x) = f(x + \phi(x))$?  (But I don't know to what extent such a solution exists, or is unique.)

Comment: With @LSpice’s nice idea we basically want to find an $f,F,\phi,\psi$ such that we have some subset of $S \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ where for every $x \in S$  $f(x+\phi(x)) = \phi(x)$ and $F(x+\psi(x)) = \psi(x)$ and $(\psi)’ = \phi$ seeing that it’s 3 equations and 4 unknown functions this should probably be possible. Adding the condition $F’ = f$ gives us 4 equations and 4 unknowns so perhaps with some luck that’s also tractable.

Comment: If we assume we can take function inverses easily. Then if $T = x + \psi(x)$ then $\psi(T^{-1}) = F$ and similarly if $Q = x + \psi’(x)$ then $\psi’(Q^{-1}) = f$. So given a choice of $\psi$ you can formally speaking find the $F,f,\phi$ using this procedure. The situation gets a lot harder when adding the $F’ = f$ constraint

Comment: Namely instead of picking any $\psi$ you must find a $\psi$ s.t. $\psi’(T^{-1}) (T^{-1})’ = \psi’(Q^{-1})$ which is a highly non linear equation since $T,Q$ depend on $\psi$ too, still unless something crazy is happening, this probably has some non trivial solutions. And once we find one such $\psi$ everything else falls into place

Comment: One possible not so trivial solution is $\phi(x)=f(x)=c$, $\psi(x)=c x$, $F(x)=c x/(1+c)$.

Comment: I think one can construct higher order solutions using a power series ansatz for $\phi(x)$ and $f(x)$. I found a linear and a quadratic solution in $\phi$, but I have to go to bed now :-).

Comment: @FredHucht has turned this into a quite interesting question. It would be nice if you revealed whether that's the question you intended.

Comment: Yes! My original intent was to find any such construction, and I think the way this has progressed satisfies that.

Comment: Then you should consider to accept the corresponding answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on others and my comments, one can construct arbitrary solutions to the problem using a Taylor series ansatz. Use the functional equations from the comments
\begin{align}
\phi(x)&=f(x+\phi(x))\tag{1a}\label{eq:1a}\\
\psi(x)&=F(x+\psi(x))\tag{1b}\label{eq:1b}
\end{align}
fulfilling $\phi(x) = \psi'(x)$.
Insert the Taylor expansions
\begin{align}
\phi(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\phi^{(k)}(0)}{k!} \, x^k \tag{2a}\\
f(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(\phi(0))}{k!} \, (x-\phi(0))^k\tag{2b}
\end{align}
into \eqref{eq:1a} to get
\begin{align}
f^{(0)}(\phi(0)) &= \phi(0)\\
f^{(1)}(\phi(0)) &= \frac{\phi'(0)}{1+\phi'(0)}\\
f^{(2)}(\phi(0)) &= \frac{\phi''(0)}{(1+\phi'(0))^3} \\
f^{(3)}(\phi(0)) &= \frac{\phi'''(0) (1+\phi'(0))-3 \phi''(0)^2}{(1+\phi'(0))^5} \label{eq:3}\tag{3}\\
&\vdots
\end{align}
as well as the corresponding coefficients of $F$,
\begin{align}
F^{(0)}(0) &= 0 \\
F^{(1)}(0) &= \frac{\phi(0)}{1+\phi(0)} \\
F^{(2)}(0) &= \frac{\phi'(0)}{(1+\phi(0))^3} \\
F^{(3)}(0) &= \frac{\phi''(0) (1+\phi(0))-3 \phi'(0)^2}{(1+\phi(0))^5}. \label{eq:4}\tag{4}\\
&\vdots
\end{align}
For $\phi(0)=0$ we can now require that $F'(x)=a f(x)$ to get two solutions: $\phi(x)\equiv 0$ and
\begin{align}
\phi^{(1)}(0) &= a-1 \label{eq:5}\tag{5}\\
\phi^{(2)}(0) &= \frac{3a^2(a-1)}{a+1} \\
\phi^{(3)}(0) &= \frac{3 (a-1) a^3 (5 a^3+5 a^2+5 a-4)}{(a+1)^2 (a^2+a+1)} \\
\phi^{(4)}(0) &= \frac{15 (a-1) a^4 (7 a^6+7 a^5+14 a^4-5 a^3+11 a^2-20 a+4)}{(a+1)^3 (a^2+1) (a^2+a+1)} \\
\phi^{(5)}(0) &= \frac{45 (a-1) a^5 p_5(a)}{(a+1)^4 (a^2+1) (a^2+a+1)^2 (a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1)}\\
&\vdots
\end{align}
with $p_5(a)=(21 a^{13}+63 a^{12}+147 a^{11}+175 a^{10}$${}+231 a^9+104 a^8+75 a^7-109 a^6$${}-101 a^5-189 a^4-59 a^3-32 a^2+68 a-8)$, which reduces to $\phi(x)\equiv 0$ for $a\to 1$.

As the denominator looks familiar to me (from some $q$ series), this solution might be written down in closed form.

Some Mathematics code:

```
ordfs = 5;
\[Phi]s[x_] = Series[\[Phi][x], {x, 0, ordfs}](*/.\[Phi][0]->0*)
fs[x_] = Series[f[x], {x, \[Phi][0], ordfs}(*/.\[Phi][0]->0*)]
CoefficientList[Normal[\[Phi]s[x] - f[x + \[Phi]s[x]]], x]
sof = FullSimplify[Solve[% == 0, fs[x][[3]] /. Rational[_, _] :> 1]]
\[Psi]s[x_] = Integrate[\[Phi]s[x], x]
ordFs = Length[(\[Psi]s[x] - F[x + \[Psi]s[x]])[[3]]] - 1;
Fs[x_] = Series[F[x], {x, 0, ordFs}]
CoefficientList[Normal[\[Psi]s[x] - F[x+\[Psi]s[x]]], x]
soF = Simplify[Solve[% == 0, Table[Derivative[k][F][0], {k,0,ordFs}]]]

Simplify[Normal[\[Phi]s[x] - f[x + \[Phi]s[x]]] /. sof]
Simplify[Normal[\[Psi]s[x] - F[x + \[Psi]s[x]]] /. soF]
```

**Update 16.12.23:**

Noting that the Taylor series of $f(x)$ and $F(x)$ in \eqref{eq:3} and \eqref{eq:4} only differ by an additional derivative order, we can set $\phi(x)=\psi(x)=e^x$ to get $f(x)=F(x)$ (use the integration constant $C=1$). The resulting common series expansion [A274447](https://oeis.org/A274447) can be identified as the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), also known as ProductLog, such that
\begin{align}\label{eq:6}\tag{6}
\phi(x)=\psi(x)=e^x \Rightarrow f(x)=F(x)=W(e^x).
\end{align}
Indeed, this solution fulfills the functional equation \eqref{eq:1a}, as
\begin{align}
e^x &= f(x + e^x) = W(e^{x+e^x}) \label{eq:7a}\tag{7a}\\
\Leftrightarrow\quad
\phi &= f(\ln\phi + \phi) = W(\phi \, e^\phi) \label{eq:7b}\tag{7b},
\end{align}
which is the definition of $W$. See also [MO:417026](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417026).

**Update 18.12.23:**

Playing around with the large number of identities for Lambert's W, a more general solution combo reads
\begin{align}
\phi(x) &= e^{a x + b} \label{eq:8a}\tag{8a}\\
\psi(x) &= \phi'(x)=a e^{a x + b} \label{eq:8b}\tag{8b}\\
f(x)    &= a^{-1} W(a \, \phi(x)) \label{eq:8c}\tag{8c}\\
F(x)    &= a^{-1} W(a \, \psi(x)) \label{eq:8d}\tag{8d},
\end{align}
with arbitrary $a,b$.

Comment: What about convergence?

Comment: @PietroMajer convergence of the functional equation or convergence of the Taylor series? Anyway, I have not checked it.

Comment: I mean the convergence of the power  solution series with $F'=af". It doesn't seem  obvious to me that the formal series have positive radius of convergence.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are just looking for a pair $f$ and $F$, you don't have to solve a functional equation for $\varphi$ and $\psi$. Take for instance $\varphi(x)=\sin(x)$, $\psi(x)=\cos(x)$. Then $I+\varphi$ and $I+\psi$ are both homeomorphisms $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, so you can define $f := \varphi\circ(I +\varphi)^{-1}$ and $F:=\psi\circ(I+\psi)^{-1}$.

*Rmk* For a smooth example (actually, analytic) you may take $\varphi(x)=a\sin(x)$, $\psi(x)=a\cos(x)$ with $|a|<1$, so that now $I+\varphi$ and $I+\psi$ are smooth diffeos. Of course, if you don't insist that the functions be defined on the whole line, there is even more freedom in the choice of $\varphi$.

Comment: Are you using $I$ for the identity map $I(x) = x$ here?

Comment: Yes, exactly $\phantom{} $, and $(I+\varphi)^{-1}$ denotes the compositional inverse of $I+\varphi$

Comment: Possibly Lagrange inversion can be used to connect your answer to the answer of Fred Hucht

Comment: As to just “find  $\phi$ solving $\phi(x)=f(x+\phi(x))$ given $f$, if $f$ is analytic you can use the analytic implicit function theorem to solve locally $\phi(x)=f(x+\phi(x))$, in a nbd of  a point $x_0$, with $\phi(x_0)=y_0$, provided $x_0=f(x_0+y_0)$ and  $f’(x_0+y_0)\neq0$;  so that the series solution  has indeed positive radius of convergence. Similarly for $\psi$. But if the  problem is  finding $\phi,\psi,f ,F$  also with $\phi’=\psi$ and $F’=f$, then I’m not sure how  one can prove that the formal series solutions do converge…